# Счетчик на setInterval с данными из input

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Хочу написать счетчик обратного отсчета(минуты, секунды) на чистом JS(ES6+),при этом минуты и секунды задаются из полей input.

```
let countMin = +min.value; //значение минут из поля input
let countSec = +sec.value; //значение секунд из поля input

let counter = setInterval(timerFunc, 1000);

function timerFunc() {
    --countSec;
    if (countSec <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        timer.innerHTML = `EXPIRED`;
        return;
    }

    timer.innerHTML = `${countMin} : ${countSec}`;
}
```

Не знаю как сделать вывод в формате 00:00 и отсчет минут когда секунды доходят до 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function timerFunc() {
  if (countSec-- == 0) {
    countMin--;
    countSec = 59;
  }
  timer.innerHTML = `${(countMin+'').padStart(2, 0)}:${(countSec+'').padStart(2, 0)}`;
  if (countMin <= 0 && countSec <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    timer.innerHTML = `EXPIRED`;
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но выдает ошибку countMin.padStart is not a function, радактор подмечает(padStart не существует в типе number)

Comment: @zippo `(countMin+'').padStart(...`